# How to filter data in dropbox in another dropbox? php mysqli

Tags: php

Interface

[image: Interface]

My Database

[image: My Database]

I want to filter 'model' by selecting in 'brand'.
Example:

```
brand>>Cardillac   
model>>STS  
XLR  
CTS  
Escalade  
SRX  
BLS  
Seville  
Allante  
ATS  
CT6  
Eldorado  
Fleetwood  
XT5  
Deville
```

Comment: Is there any code or attempts that you've tried to achieve this?

Comment: yes sir.. but it only shows all data from database

Answer (score 0):

This is easiest to use

```js
var bmw   = new Array("328", "540", "740", "x5", "x6");
var mercedes   = new Array("C240", "cls320", "A160", "E32");

function set_player() {
  var select_brand = document.search.brand;
  var select_model = document.search.model;
  var selected_brand = select_brand.options[select_brand.selectedIndex].value;

  select_model.options.length=0;
  if (selected_brand == "Bmw"){
    for(var i=0; i<bmw.length; i++)
    select_model.options[select_model.options.length] = new Option(bmw[i]);
  }
  if (selected_brand == "Mercedes"){
    for(var i=0; i<mercedes.length; i++)
    select_model.options[select_model.options.length] = new Option(mercedes[i]);
  }

}
```

```html
<!doctype>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset = "utf-8" />
<script src="js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="search">
  <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Brand:</td><td>
    <select name="brand" onchange="set_player()">
    <option selected="selected" style="background-color:#FFCC00;">Select Brand</option>
    <option value="Bmw">Bmw</option>
    <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td>Model:</td><td>
    <select name="model">
    <option>First Select Brand</option>
    </select>
    </td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
      </label></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I cant use that because i have database.

Comment: i understand,  I wrote it easy